# Как запаковать html в exe?

Tags: html, exe

Как запаковать папку с файлом index.html и принадлежащими ему файлами (скрипты, картинки, другие страницы)?

Comment: Попробуй через visual-basic.

Answer (score 4):

1. В exe запаковать можно, но придется искать движок, который сможет отобразить встроенный HTML. В любом случае это дурной тон. Просмотровщик для различных типов гипертекстовых документов стоит уже на практически любом компьютере, поэтому плодить сущности не стоит. А я бы вообще параноил - не троян ли мне пытаются подсунуть
2. Как правильно ответили выше существует формат файлов CHM. Это по сути компилированный HTML. Т.е. архив, в котором может быть несколько html-страниц, картинок, файлов и прочих типов ресурсов. И все в одном файле, открываемом специальной программой просмотра. Для создания CHM файла существует специальный класс программ - CHM-компиляторы. Их ассортимент начинается от родного M$ HTML Help Workshop, а заканчивается более удобными сторонними программами, например, htm2chm.
3. Также существует файл MHT. Это также по сути архивированный HTML и связанные с ним ресурсы, только особенностью является сжатие при помоши MIME. Сейчас любой нормальный браузер умеет как открывать такие файлы, так и сохранять в этот формат.

Comment: Да рад бы я использовать chm, только бесят меня вся эта бесполезная муть в окне программки от Microsoft. Мне кажется, что то, что я хочу запихнуть, в chm не будет смотреться.

Comment: Зря так думаете.

Comment: Кто мне объяснит, почему сегодня форматирование текста слетает на ура?

Comment: "Мне кажется, что то, что я хочу запихнуть, в chm не будет смотреться."  -нужно пробовать и смотреть, что получается. Если именно в CHM, то желательно результат изучить в нескольких просмотровщиках (в частности, есть их зоопарк под linux'ом).

Answer (score 2):

Может будет достаточно запаковать это в chm ?

В виндовсе будет открываться как приложение. С возможностью поиска по всем файлам что вы туда запаковали

Comment: "С возможностью поиска по всем файлам что вы туда запаковали" - ой, не факт, ой, не факт...

Answer (score 2):

Все зависит от вашей задачи. Если вы знаете HTML/JS и таким образом хотите "написать" приложение под Windows - это, извините, самый плохой способ это сделать. Вы не сможете использовать ни преимущества API Windows ни преимущества браузера (я имею ввиду вы скорее всего сможете отображать только статический контент да и какой бы инструмент для перевода из HTML в EXE вы не выбрали, все равно ваш HTML будет отображаться через ActiveX элемент управления Internet Explorer и не факт, что это будет IE9 (так что забудьте о CSS3, HTML5.)

Если вы хотите сделать набор статических файлов для eLearning-приложения то так умеет Help & Manual (http://www.ec-software.com/products_hm_overview.html) да и так такого софта хватает: http://www.google.com/search?q=html+2+exe

Answer (score -2):

Зипом запаковать каталог и добавить его в ресурсы экзе, потом извлечь при необходимости через LZ-api:
[File Compression and Decompression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364219(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: А чем выводить (отображать) HTML?

Comment: Распаковать разумеется, во временный каталог. Да и проэмулировать фс не составляет труда. Так например из памяти модуля загружаются.